# flock: the right way to truncate with sysopen

Tags: perl, file-io, truncate, flock

Are these three versions equivalent?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use Fcntl qw(:flock :seek);
my $fh;

sysopen $fh, $file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC or die $!;
flock $fh, LOCK_EX or die $!;
say $fh 'something';
close $fh;

sysopen $fh, $file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT or die $!;
flock $fh, LOCK_EX or die $!;
seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET or die $!;
truncate $fh, 0 or die $!;
say $fh 'something';
close $fh;

sysopen $fh, $file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT or die $!;
flock $fh, LOCK_EX or die $!;
truncate $fh, 0 or die $!;
say $fh 'something';
close $fh;
```

Comment: They ought to be equivalent – but my question is why you are using sysopen in the first place. (Edit: The “correctest” way quite certainly is the `O_TRUNC` flag)

Comment: I've read this in a tutorial: for a normal `open $fh, '>', $file` the `flock` comes to late - the file is already overwritten.

Comment: use `flock` on helper files so your main file doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted to flock before truncating. Of course, this rules out your first solution as well. You can avoid truncation with `+<` mode when using normal `open`. What are the exact requirements you have? What actual problem are you trying to solve through flocking?

Comment: or `+>>` to avoid truncate and have write ability. btw. `+<` fails if there is no file?

Comment: @amon: Maybe it's more for fun than really needed. I have a script which writes to a file: when I call the script two times, the flock would prevent that both instances write to same time to the file.

Comment: Ok, I have to decide if I use `+<` or if I leave the `flock` away.

Comment: @amon: could you make that an answer (rules out the first solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to open a file, lock it, and then truncate it without any possibility that another process that is competing for that lock might see a truncated file. This poses several restrictions:

- A lock has to be obtained before truncation. This rules out the first solution, as it does the truncation before the lock can be acquired.
- The file handle cannot be reopened with another mode, or the lock would be lost. This means that the truncation can't be done by reopening.

Thus the ideal solution has the following steps:

1. The file is opened without truncating, e.g. with sysopen, or the open modes `>>`, `+<`. The sysopen option `O_TRUNC` or the open modes `>`, `+>` etc. **must not** be used here.
2. A lock is acquired.
3. Truncation is performed. As `open` would create a new filehandle, the `truncate` function **must** be used here.
4. If the file was opened in append mode, it is neccessary to `seek` to the beginning of the file.

Your first solution truncates before aquiring the lock, and can therefore be ruled out.

Your second and third solution are both possible, although the `seek` is unneccessary.

Other solutions could use regular `open`:

```
open my $fh, "+<", $file;  # Achtung: fails if the file doesn't exist
flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
truncate $fh;

# or:
open my $fh, ">>", $file;
flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
truncate $fh;
seek 0, 0;
```

In many cases, it may be preferable to use an unrelated file as lock, thus avoiding difficulties with reopening. This would look like:

```
# adapted from perldoc -f flock

sub lock {
  my $file = shift;
  open my $fh, "<", ".$file.lock";
  flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
  return $fh;
}

sub unlock {
  my $fh = shift;
  flock $fh, LOCK_UN;
}

my $lock = lock($file);
open my $fh, ">", $file;
...
unlock($lock);
```

Of course, all related processes have to honour this interface and create an appropriate lockfile.